# content-modelling vs. content-modeling which tag spelling to use?

Tags: discussion, tags

So far we only have one question ([What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a "General Content" Schema?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/364/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-a-general-content-schema) ) tagged with [content-modelling](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-modelling).

Before we get any additional questions using this tag I wanted to pose the question should we use the British English spelling of the tag: [content-modelling](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-modelling) or the American English spelling of the tag: [content-modeling](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-modeling)?

Also, I guess in general which direction re: spelling should we lean when creating tags (and editing questions?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDL Tridion has the standard to use [American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants) which would make it content-modeling. I personally find the AE versions easier to read, but I guess the British will have a different opinion (was always fun to give VBScript trainings in England and explain `Call lObjChildComponent.Localize` to the trainees).

In any case we should probably be smart and create both and make one a synonym of the other. But then of course the question still remains, which would be the synonym of what.

My preference would be [content-modeling](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-modeling), but I have no problem accepting BE.

Comment: I created the content-modeling tag and retagged the one question to use it. Bart, maybe you can create a Synonym mapping content-modelling to content-modeling? It looks like we're close to having some users who can vote for them.

Comment: I don't have enough answer votes on the tag to create a synonym (I didn't answer that one ;o), but once its there I can vote for it. Probably enough for now if we just focus on getting all tag wikis filled and synonyms can come later. Since a synonym is automatically retagging the question they have no rush.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that either is fine. I think tags like these should be considered synonymous. The only situations in which one valid spelling is prioritised over another should be when

- Existing convention dictates it (such as "HTTP Referer," which I don't think is actually valid in any culture but still used by convention).
- The term is a proper noun; product names etc.
- The term has a product-specific meaning, e.g. 'localization'.

As "content modelling" is a general term, I don't think it matters too much. If anything, I'd go with the American-English version for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Agree with all you mention, but just wanted to point out that I think when we create a tag synonym, it means that there is a "original" tag and one (or more) synonyms for it. If somebody tags something with a synonym, it is automatically replaced by the "original". But we could create both tags and suggest each as a synonym of each other and then let the voting on the synonym decide which one becomes the original.

Comment: Hadn't occurred to me that's how synonyms work. My vote is for "modeling," for consistency's sake.

Comment: Looks like on Meta SO there is a standard that [tags should be in US-English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us), question text should NOT be edited simply for changing US-English vs. British-English spellings and there seems to be disagreement on how to handle titles.

Comment: Sounds like a familiar discussion, hmmm... original content in a source language such as US-English, but local "variations" somehow connected to the original. Nah...